# Bound for a double sum and power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, upper-lower-bounds

I am looking for a bound for the sum of of the following form:

$$\sum_{1 \leq l <k \leq n} (k-l)^{\gamma}$$
and $\gamma >1$.
Does somebody knows what would be an upper bound for such sum involving preferably only a sum with summation over $k$ and involving parameter $\gamma?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given sum can be expressed as $$
\sum_{1 \leq l <k \leq n} (k-l)^{\gamma}=\sum_{l=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{l-1}{k^{\gamma}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{(n-k)k^{\gamma}}=n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k^{\gamma}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^{\gamma+1}
$$
The last two sums can be bounded by definite integrals in the usual way.